# Reading two columns from a text file which is in scientific format and plot in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a text file which includes the following two column data in scientific format. The first column is time the second is data. I couldn't achieve to read this data and plot time vs data.

```
0.000000000000000e+000  0.000000e+000
9.765624975344167e-010  9.765624e-008
1.953124995068833e-009  1.953125e-007
3.531088169181148e-004  3.458634e-002
7.062156807112345e-004  6.807133e-002
1.059322544504354e-003  1.004552e-001
1.412429408297474e-003  1.317378e-001
1.765536272090594e-003  1.619193e-001
2.118643135883714e-003  1.909997e-001
2.471749999676832e-003  2.189789e-001
3.225098213962545e-003  2.749892e-001
3.978446428248258e-003  3.275717e-001
4.731794642533971e-003  3.767263e-001
5.485142856819683e-003  4.224531e-001
6.238491071105396e-003  4.647520e-001
6.991839285391109e-003  5.036230e-001
7.745187499676820e-003  5.390663e-001
8.651995535391102e-003  5.783692e-001
9.558803571105385e-003  6.148861e-001
```

I have been searching for hours but couldn't get it worked. I would be very glad if some one has experience with such task.

Comment: Please show what you've tried. You say that you couldn't get it to work - what, specifically, did you try and what did it give you (and how was this not what you needed?). Posting your problem without showing any evidence of your attempts at a solution just looks like asking someone else to do your (home)work for you.
Look here for how to write a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have tried maybe 20 different ways

Comment: As far as I, and anyone else who is looking at this question can tell, you've tried zero ways, because that's all there is evidence for

Comment: @atomant: If you tried something, please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you did not, have a look at the built-in `csv` module providing some basic functions to import data or `pandas` which is more powerful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what you tried 20 times. It is quite straightforward using `loadtxt` and `plot`. The code is as short as

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.loadtxt('test.dat')
x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]
# x, y = np.loadtxt('test.dat', unpack=True) # Alternative as suggested by Jayjayyy

plt.plot(x,y, '-bx')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I guess this interpolates curve fitting the points. Is it possible to find the  y data for a nygiven x data in the range for this plot? Or only for the array points? Thanks

Comment: @atomant: No, it does not interpolate. It looks like a continuous line without markers. Now I use crosses to show the data points

Comment: Downvote? Really?

Answer (score 1):

Even without `np.loadtxt` as in @Bazingaa's answer, you can do it with standard `float()` conversion:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    print([float(x) for x in line.strip().split()])
```